# Is it possible to show that the determinant of the following matrix is greater than one?

Tags: matrices

Is it possible show that the determinant of the following matrix is greater than one?

$\det\left(I+AB+CD\right)\geq1$

where $A, B$ and $C$ and $D$ are positive semi-definite.

Comment: Are the matrices Hermitian? What do you mean by positive semi-definite?

Comment: They are real symmetric matrices such that x'Ax >= 0, for any vector x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible.

Take $A=\begin{bmatrix} 10 & 20 \\ 20 & 50 \end{bmatrix}$,
$B=\begin{bmatrix} 10 & -10 \\ -10 & 20 \end{bmatrix}$,
$C=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 150 \end{bmatrix}$ and $D = I$.

Then $A,B,D >0$, $C \ge 0$ and
$\det(I + AB +CD ) = -4149$.

Comment: If $[C]_{11}$ is replaced by $1$ then $\det$ is still negative, so we may take $C>0$ as well.